# Javascript parse string as es6 function

Tags: javascript, string, function, parsing, ecmascript-6

I'm getting string representation for es6 function like this

```
"return (...args) => {↵    console.log('HIGHLIGHTLOADER', args);↵  };"
```

from this string, I need to create a function

```
const func = (...args) => {
  console.log('HIGHLIGHTLOADER', args);
}
```

Without using **eval** How can i parse this string?.

Comment: By "parse" - do you mean you want to create an _executable_ function you can directly call? Or by "parse" do you mean you want the AST of the function? If it's the former then no, you cannot. That's _exactly_ what `eval` is for. And what you're asking is horribly unsafe.

Comment: Also, _why_ do you want to do this? What is the use-case?

Comment: @Dai yes I want to create executable function.

Comment: Why without eval? It's literally made for this use.

Comment: @Dai user can add multiple calls when some event triggers, we are getting just this string rep of function.

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa What is the nature of this application? How does it run (in the browser? server-side NodeJS? something else?). Does your application design actually call for the execution of **untrusted, unverified user-supplied scripts?** How does your program handle someone providing a script that steals cookies and sends them to a criminal botnet or does JavaScript cryptocurrency mining?

Comment: You can use Function instead eval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) *(after removing invalid characters like `↵`)*

```js
const input = "return (...args) => { console.log('HIGHLIGHTLOADER', args); };"
const func = (new Function(input)());

func(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: I note that this approach has **the same security issues** as `eval` - so any company policy that forbids `eval` must also forbid use of the `Function(string)` constructor.

Comment:  This. If you really want to stick with this approach, then only ever use this if you're 100% sure that the content of `input` will be safe and not controlled by anyone else but you.